# Typescript cannot find local es6 module; error TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am having a hard time getting typescript to recognize the shape of a local es6 module:

**convert-time.js**

```
export const minutes = sec => sec * 60
export const hours = sec => minutes(sec) * 60
export const days = sec => hours(sec) * 24
export const weeks = sec => days(sec) * 24
export const years = sec => days(sec) * 365
```

*Note: I would like to figure out how to get this to work without just changing `convert-time.js` to a typescript file.*

Here is the file I am trying to import it into:

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/convert-time.d.ts" />

import { minutes, days } from '../test/helpers/convert-time'
```

Here is the type definition file I created:

**convert-time.d.ts:**

```
declare module "convert-time" {
  export function minutes(sec: number): number;
  export function hours(sec: number): number;
  export function days(sec: number): number;
  export function weeks(sec: number): number;
  export function years(sec: number): number;
}
```

And here is my tsconfig:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/convert-time.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Steps tried:**

- Searched StackOverflow for `error TS2307: Cannot find module`. Most questions are regarding external modules which have type definitions. I couldn't find an example of a local module.
- Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html
- Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html
- Added `typings/convert-time.d.ts` to the `files` section in `tsconfig.json`.
- Added `/// <reference path='../../typings/convert-time.d.ts' />` to `index.ts`

None of the above worked! What dark magic must I learn to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: In your `compilerOptions` you need to have `allowJs: true` to allow for JavaScript files otherwise it will thow an error.

Comment: I had this problem. The allowJs: true solved the issue for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Regarding ES6**

Since you are trying to inter-operate with an ES6 module you will either"

**a)** Change your `tsconfig.json` to target ES6 and emit ES6 modules like this:

```
{
  ...
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "es6",
  ...
}
```

However I don't think you can use ES6 modules yet in NodeJS.

or:

**b)** Let TypeScript transpile the ES6 JavaScript module down to ES5 by enabling JavaScript processing in your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` - like the below and making sure that the .js file is included/not excluded:

```
{
  ...
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "allowJs": true,
  ...
}
```

**Regarding your Type Declarations**

Have a read at my blog on how TypeScript discovers typings/type declarations and what it expects to see here: https://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript

It appears that this JavaScript file is your own code (not an NPM module), so:

1. You don't need the `/// <reference path="../typings/convert-time.d.ts" />` as long as the file is not excluded or included in `tsconfig.json`
2. Ensure `convert-time.d.ts` is in the same directory as `convert-time.js`
3. You don't need to declare a module, so remove the `declare module "convert-time" {` bit. This is because by having the .d.ts next to the .js it's an "external" module rather than "ambient' (see my blog) (you will need the `declare` bit if e.g. you were creating typings which are living in your own code for a NPM package)

Basically:

**../test/helpers/convert-time.js:**

```
export const minutes = sec => sec * 60
export const hours = sec => minutes(sec) * 60
export const days = sec => hours(sec) * 24
export const weeks = sec => days(sec) * 24
export const years = sec => days(sec) * 365
```

**../test/helpers/convert-time.ts.d:**

```
export function minutes(sec: number): number;
export function hours(sec: number): number;
export function days(sec: number): number;
export function weeks(sec: number): number;
export function years(sec: number): number;
```

**index.ts:**

```
import { minutes, days } from '../test/helpers/convert-time';
```

**tsconfig.json (for ES5 transpiling)**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "files": [
    "/test/helpers/convert-time.ts.d",
    "/test/helpers/convert-time.js",
    "index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, for the thorough explanation! This did help me understand better how typescript searches for type definitions. I got rid of all of the ambient definitions and references. The build step completes successfully now, but unfortunately at runtime I get "Unexpected token export". Any ideas?

Comment: @Raine Where is the error coming from and what is the code?

Comment: The code is exactly as you specified. The error occurs in convert-time.js when the server starts, at run-time. It looks like an extra transpilation step is needed somewhere to convert these into commonjs modules?

Comment: Note: at the start of step B, `commondjs` should instead be written as `commonjs`.

Comment: @JamieBirch Good spot! Fixed the typo.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the exact error in the original question, but the "allowJs" advice seems to have worked for several others, and my recreation is indeed working.